# I want to convert a report into a form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, report

I'm doing a project using php and mySQL and what I want to do is take a report I've generated, (Scholarships.php) and allow me to submit data from it.

Specifically,

I have a giant table of scholarships that can be added to. In a form page where people can apply for these scholarships, I included an iFrame that displays Scholarships.php. What I want to do is set up check boxes next to each scholarship so that an applying student could select various scholarships, hit submit, and the results dump into a Junction table I've created.

The part I don't know how to do is converting the report I've generated, and converting it into a form I can use for the check boxes.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<h2>";
echo "ID - $row[0]";
echo "</h2>";
echo "<p>";
echo "$row[1].";
echo "</p>";
echo "<h2>";
echo "$row[2].";
echo "</h2>";
echo "<p>";
echo $row[3]."";
echo "</p>";
echo "<p>";
echo $row[4]."";
echo "</p>";
echo "<p>";
echo $row[5]."";
echo "</p>";
}
```

How from this snippet would I place checkboxes that post to another table?

Comment: By generating appropriate html code for a form . There are lots of tutorials out there on html forms and on how to generate html forms from php.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp You need to create an html `form`.